# Temporizador para um comando script Shell

Tags: bash, shell-script

Boa tarde pessoal,

Tenho vontade de escrever um script com um comando que captura todo fluxo de rede wireless ao derredor da minha empresa e armazenar em um arquivo de texto. Atualmente faço assim:

```
airmon-ng start 'nome da placa de rede wifi'
airodump-ng -a wlan0mon 2>&1 | tee captura.txt
```

Acontece que para interromper a captura é necessário pressionar CTRL+C e eu tenho que capturar por 10, 15 ou 20 minutos, para que o arquivo não fique gigantesco!

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para que esse processo interrompa sem precisar pressionar CTRL+C?

Comment: Questões de automação e infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su], [sf] ou https://unix.stackexchange.com/ conforme o assunto. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Pensei que a pergunta dele era valida, uma vez que é sobre programação em bash e shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o kill -INT, que faz o trabalho do Ctrl+C

```
# Roda o script de captura em background
./x.sh &
# Aguarda 1 minuto (seconds)
sleep 60
# Kill 
killall -INT airodump-ng
```

Opcionalmente, pode usar killall -9 airodump-ng

Testado com bash 4.3

Comment: Obrigado cara! Vc salvou a minha vida!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o comando [timeout](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) que é justamente oque você precisa, rodar um programa e o encerrar apos um tempo determinado.

exemplos:

`timeout 15 ping 8.8.8.8`

No seu caso acho que ficaria algo do tipo

`timeout 20m ./seu_script`

O legal desse comando é que você pode selecionar que tipo de signal vc quer que o programa receba, um `SIG KILL` ou `SIG TERM` que é mais amigavel,

Comment: Sua opção, a principio me pareceu a melhor, mas para manter o processo automático, a do colega @Incrivel Monstro Verde Cabelud foi mais performática! O timeout, embora realmente interrompa o processo, exige alguma ação após a execução.